# Convergence of gradient divided by distance

Tags: limits, derivatives, differential-geometry, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I want to show the following. If $f$ is $C^2(X,\mathbb{R})$, where $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is compact then;

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|\nabla f(x_n)-\nabla f(x)|}{|x_n-x|}
\end{equation}
converges for all sequences $\{x_n\}$ tending to $x$.

I think I must use a Taylor expansion, but I am a bit confused in the higher dimensions on how this works. I know that at some point I must use the fact that $X$ is compact and the derivatives are continuous to say that all derivatives are bounded but I'm confused about how to write this formally. Also, is there a simple expression for what the above converges to?

Comment: Are you assuming that $\nabla f(x) = 0$? Otherwise I don't see how this could be true.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I missed the gradient at the top. Thank you for spotting this!

Comment: Saying that $f$ is $\mathscr{C}^2$ means that the map $a\mapsto{\rm d}_af$ is $\mathscr{C}^1$.
Here ${\rm d}_af\in\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^k\mathbin;\mathbb{R})$ is expressed by
$\forall h\in\mathbb{R}^k\ {\rm d}_af(h)=(\nabla_{\!a}f)\cdot h$.
Hence the differentiability of $a\mapsto{\rm d}_af$ is equivalent to the differentiability of $a\mapsto\nabla_{\!a}f$.

Comment: I see... so in that case what would my limit converge to?

Comment: Well, from a practical point of view, $f$ has $k$ first derivatives $\displaystyle a\mapsto\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, which are (the components of $\nabla_a(f)$) of class $\mathscr{C}^1$ and have themselves $k$ continuous derivatives $\displaystyle a\mapsto\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\cdot$
Now you probably know some facts about the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of $f$.

Comment: I think my confusion is coming from the placement of the absolute values... my understanding is that the hessian is the jacobian of a gradient. Each element of the hessian is like a limit of the form I have above, but with $d_\alpha$ in the place of $\nabla$ and a vector in the direction of $\alpha$ on the bottom. But I'm still not sure how to use this to evaluate what I have with the absolute values placed where I have them.

Comment: Your notations are confusing.
I thought that $x$ (and $x_n$) were elements of $X\subset\Bbb{R}^k$ and that $\nabla f(x)$ was the gradient of $f$ evaluated at $x$ (what I wrote $\nabla_xf$); if so, it is an element of $\Bbb{R}^k$ and you rather should have written $\frac{\Vert\nabla f(x_n)-\nabla f(x)\Vert}{\Vert x_n-x\Vert}$ (or $\frac{\Vert\nabla_{x_n} f-\nabla_x f\Vert}{\Vert x_n-x\Vert}\Big)\cdot$

Comment: On the other hand, if $\nabla f(x)$ means $(\nabla_{\!y}f)\cdot x={\rm d}_yf(x)\in\Bbb{R}$ for some fixed point $y\in\Bbb{R}^k$ independent of $x$ and the $x_n$, this is another question, regarding the differentiability of the map
${\rm d}_yf\colon\vec u\mapsto(\nabla_{\!y}f)\cdot\vec u$.

Comment: What you originally thought was what I had intended. $\nabla$ is the gradient - perhaps I was confused in my last answer, sorry - I am unsure how to write my limit in terms of the Hessian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143025/discussion-between-jp-boucheron-and-masontep).